# Totally new at codeing and im not able to find out why my loop skips my Scanner function

Tags: java, while-loop

My while loop does not go to my next user input "y1".. it just loops back.
user input "y" works, i give a value, it calculates, waits the 2000 ms and then loops. Any ideas?
Sorry for the messy code, still learning.

```
   if (x1.equalsIgnoreCase("JA")) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Hvad er beløbet?");
                double y = scanner.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(y * 6.6296);
                wait(2000);
                System.out.println("Vil du indtaste et nyt beløb?");
                String y1 = scanner.nextLine();
                if (y1.equalsIgnoreCase("JA")) {
                }
                
                if (y1.equalsIgnoreCase("NEJ")) {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Does it print out "Hvad er beløbet?" again?

Comment: I would like to suggest that you print something out right before your if statement.

Comment: I am entirely convinced that (a) Scanner makes for a lousy user interface, and (b) it should not be taught to beginners as 'the' way to get user input,

Comment: Yeah, so it waits the 2000 ms and prints ("Vil du indtaste et nyt beløb?");
Then goes to ("Hvad er beløbet?"); right after.